# StackExchange Simulator

Tags: app, website, data-dump, fun

### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

### About

Have you thought that most Questions were too boring or made too much sense?

Then this is perfect for you: Nonsense Questions and Answers based on every Stack Exchange site.

How good do you know the Stack Exchange sites? Try out [the Quiz](https://se-simulator.lw1.at/quiz/easy)!

#### License

All code is licensed under GPL-3.0 and can be found here: https://github.com/Findus23/se-simulator
All data on the site is licensed under Creative Commons BY-SA 3.0

#### Check it out

### https://se-simulator.lw1.at/

#### Platform

This is an interactive website that allows voting for funny questions and answers.

### Contact

I'm an astronomy student who writes (more or less useful) software in his free time. Check out https://lw1.at for more of my projects.

### Code

A python script uses the StackExchange datadump to create a Markov Chain based on every StackExchange site. (using the great [markovify library](https://github.com/jsvine/markovify/)).

All created data is saved into a MySQL-Database and used to create the website in [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

Hope you like it and find it as funny as I do.

Comment: "_From a quick look at the National Cancer Institute's Division of Labor Statistics, the hearsay rule. In the case in the square of the Bimini Road._" - se-simulator regarding if greeks driving affected whales.

Answer (score 3):

<s>[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)</s> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Can you please change the "**NEXT**" button color. Currently it looks like the button is disabled, can you change the color to green or better one..

> [image: Next button]

Comment: Commited and deployed: https://github.com/Findus23/se-simulator/commit/60d58e8f5dced67f2595098eed6352fdd67273df

Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @LukasWinkler Looks fine now.

Answer (score 3):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Can you add a green to the votes to random questions on the whole questions list which are accepted by owner and add a checkmark on the accepted answer of question?

**On the questions page:**

[image: Accepted (on questions page)]

**On 2nd accepted question from questions page:**

[image: Accepted (on the 2nd accepted question from questions page)]

The accepted answer bumps to the top of the answers list unless it is the question asker's own answer, by the usual rule.